# How to retrive Integer and Timestamp value from array stored in MongoDB with Java Driver

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I did a program in Java that generates values and stores them in a `MongoDB` database in the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "destination" : "destination_1",
    "origin" : "origin1",
    "duration_value" : [
            5,
            5,
            12
    ],
    "duration_text" : [
            null,
            null,
            null
    ],
    "timestamp" : [
            ISODate("2017-05-03T15:17:12.570Z"),
            ISODate("2017-05-03T15:17:39.363Z"),
            ISODate("2017-05-06T17:16:43.925Z")
    ]}
```

As you can see there are three arrays. In `duration_value` array, they will always be stored in Integer values and in the `timestamp` array, they will always store `time stamp` values. 
I now need to retrieve the integer values that are stored in `duration_value` in order to make calculations and retrieve the values entered in the `timestamp` array, not as `DBObject` or `BasicDBObject`, but as objects in the `Timestamp` class that is comparable, to be able to do other operations. How can I do?

So far I have been able to retrieve elements from the database just as `DBObject` and not with their original types and I could not even cast the `DBObject` errors without errors. I used the following code:

```
    MongoClient mongo = null;
    DBCursor cursor = null;


    try {
        mongo = new MongoClient ("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb2");

        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("user");
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("_id", 0);
        cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

        DBObject resultElement = cursor.next(); 
        List<DBObject> list = (List<DBObject>)resultElement.get("timestamp");             

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

            System.out.println("indice: " + i + " contenuto: " + list.get(i));
        }


    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println("error : " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("error : " + e.getCause());
    }
    finally{
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Sorry for my english and thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried ? `Date date = (Date) list.get(i);` Mongo java driver maps the mongo timestamp type to java.util.Date type. You can use the new `Document` & `MongoCollection` api for type safe variant in Mongo 3.x driver version.

Comment: I honestly tried it with the integers, since I need it for the other array and since I could not even cast those I felt quite uncomfortable so and I did not try the timestamp. I tried it now and it  works, now I had to understand how to cast the other array in integer. You solved half of my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to below. Use `findOne` instead of `find` for search on `id`.

MongoDB maps timestamp to `java.util.Date` and number to `java.lang.Double`.

```
 DBObject result = table.findOne(searchQuery);

 BasicDBList number = (BasicDBList)result.get("duration_value");
 BasicDBList timestamp = (BasicDBList)result.get("timestamp");

 int integer = ((Number)number.get(i)).intValue();
 Date date = (Date) timestamp.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Java Driver API you can get basic Java types from DBObject.

You can't get Timestamp instances directly from the DBObject.

API documentation for BasicDBObject:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html

API documentation for inherited BasicBSONObject: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/org/bson/BasicBSONObject.html

There are available other Java MongoDB libraries. One of them is MongoJack is based on Java driver with Jackson library. It supports out of the box JSON to Java object mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.